# Not able to save session in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I have created a base `Page` class and trying to save object in session variable but it is giving me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. my object is initialized and have values.

I have added `enableSessionState="true"` and `sessionState mode="InProc"` settings in Web.config file.
ASP.NET State Service is also running

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        string catalog = "" + HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["c"];
        if (catalog != "")
        {
            Engine eng = new Engine();
            TEngine engine = eng.GetEngines(catalog.ToUpper());
            if (engine != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentEngine"] = engine;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" cookieless="false" />

    <pages enableSessionState="true">
      <controls>
              <add src="~/Components/menu.ascx" tagName="Menu" tagPrefix="uc" />
              <add src="~/Components/footer.ascx" tagName="Footer" tagPrefix="uc" />
              <add src="~/Component/tree.ascx" tagName="Tree" tagPrefix="uc" />

          </controls>        
        </pages>

        <httpModules>
          <add type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" name="Session"/>
        </httpModules>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's likely that the construction of your page objects occurs too early in the ASP.NET life cycle, and HttpContext.Current is not available yet. Have you tried moving this code to one of the initialization methods or some such, instead of the constructor?

Comment: Yes. I just tested code in aspx page load event and it is working as expected. it appears that Session is not available at that point HttpContext.Current is available and I am using it at the top to retrieve QueryString value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer, since it seems to have solved your problem:

The construction of your page objects occurs too early in the ASP.NET life cycle, and HttpContext.Current is not available yet. Move this code to one of the initialization methods or some such, instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.80).aspx), the `Page`'s properties (`Context`, `Request`, etc) will be assigned after the construction of the Page object. You can move the code which make use of these properties to either `Init` or `Load` event handlers.

And there is no need to use `HttpContext.Current` inside a web page. Simply use `this.Context`.

Comment: +1 There's also usually no need to do `this.Context.Session` in a web page. Instead, just use `Session`.

Comment: I had code in class constructor and Request object was not available directly so I was using HttpContext.Current to make it work and it was working for Request object but not for session. I already moved code to load event as StriplingWarrior suggest and it worked. Thanks for your help.